# Dismissed on grounds of misconduct, without police involvement

Tags: job-search, united-kingdom

If I am dismissed from my job at a Care Home on grounds of misconduct - but there is no police involvement - will this be detrimental to future criminal records checks (aka CRB check) for similar roles?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93938/discussion-on-question-by-swela-fernandez-dismissed-on-grounds-of-misconduct-wi).

Answer (score 17):

By "CRB check" I'm assuming you mean what is now the [Disclosure and Barring Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disclosure_and_Barring_Service) (DBS) check. In the general case no being dismissed for misconduct in of itself won't affect a basic DBS check as those will only look for things that resulted in a conviction or conditional caution.

A standard check will also include and cautions, reprimands and final warnings - but only those logged with the police. If there's no police involvement then there won't be any of those.

An enhanced check is more of a grey area - as it can include any information held by local police that is "considered relevant" so even if there was no police action or direct involvement if your former employer notified the police then this may or may not be held.

An "enhanced check with barred lists" is the same as the above but includes the list of people specifically barred from carrying out the role - without knowing more information about what the role was and the nature of the misconduct it's impossible to know whether this would be a possibility here.

If you're concerned you can always do a [basic check](https://www.gov.uk/criminal-record-checks-apply-role) on yourself.

If you're going for something more than a DBS check (such as SC clearance or NPPV checks) then that's a whole different can of worms!

Since this is a care home the most likely level of check would be an Enhanced check and if the role involved any duties classed as a "Regulated Activity" such as:

- Personal care (washing, toilet assistance, eating)
- Household matters (managing or handling cash, paying bills, shopping)
- Conducting affairs for the client on their behalf
- Transportation

(See [here for more complete information](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/216900/Regulated-Activity-Adults-Dec-2012.pdf) on "Regulated Activities")

Then it would be an *Enhanced with barred lists* check - that being the case if the misconduct in question was relating to a regulated activity or to the safeguarding of clients then it's entirely possible the action would be recorded on such a check - and if severe enough it could lead to you being placed on a barred list.